# Stripping text from a string using a marker and php

Tags: php

How can i strip out the code after the "-" (including the -) in this title using php?

```
Buying a Home - Conveyancing Solicitors Dorset, Devon & Cornwall - LCS Legal Services
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function

```
$title = strtok($title, '-');
```

alternatively you can use explode function and grab required part.

```
$parts = explode('-', $title);
$title = current($parts); //first
$title = end($parts); //last
$title = $parts[0] //using index
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Buying a Home - Conveyancing Solicitors Dorset, Devon & Cornwall - LCS Legal Services
';

// find first occurrence of '-'
$pos = strpos($str, '-');

// if '-' found, take the substring from the beginning to the position found
$str = ($pos !== false) ? substr($str, 0, $pos) : $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

use explode on "-" and get first element.

```
$str = "Buying a Home - Conveyancing Solicitors Dorset, Devon & Cornwall - LCS Legal Services";
$s = explode("-",$str);
print $s[0];
```